# Rails Singular Resources is not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

According to singular resources of `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/` I created post by this command `rails g scaffold post -singular` but it created plural resources posts. So I changed it to

```
  get 'post', to: 'posts#show'

  resource :post
```

According to the guide this should show the post but actually it gives error saying that `Couldn't find Post without an ID`

Also it says I can  use the same controller for a singular route (/post) and a plural route (/posts/45), how can I do that?

Comment: DO NOT break convention unless you really really have to do. It will bite you finally.

Answer (score 2):

When visiting a singular route that points to show, you are not provided an ID, so `Post.find(params[:id])` won't work and will give you that error 'Couldn't find Post without an ID'. Since you're not given an ID param, you need to either hardcode the ID like `Post.find(1)` or do something like `current_user.post` assuming you have a user that has_one post or belongs_to post.

If you want to use both a singular route '/post' and a plural route '/posts/45', then you will need to account for both cases in your show action since both routes will point to the same action. Your show action will look like:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def show
  @post = params[:id] ? Post.find(params[:id]) : Post.find(45)
end
```